# Undo/Redo in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, state-management

I'm using Angular 7 for a system I'm building. And now i need to add an Undo/Redo feature to this application. What I'm looking for is, what are the best practices I should follow to do this? Do I need to use a state management library (NGRX, etc) for efficiency and maintainability and What are the advantages of state management libraries where we can just use angular services for example? Or would following a simple design pattern (command pattern, etc) be enough, more practical and with less additional complexity? Note that the data structure of the system is nested and complicated (5 levels of nesting)

I've tried to implement a command design pattern for this, but i want to make sure that this is the "right way" to tackle such a problem.

Comment: There’s no generic answer to this, and many routes to implementation.